# Hibernate OGM: Having trouble starting MongoDB database

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-ogm

So I'm pretty new to MongoDB as well as Hibernate and I'm trying to run a test to connect and add documents to a MongoDB database. The code ran on another machine so it should work, but I'm assuming I might have a error with MongoDB. The error starts when trying to build a EntitiyManagerFactory. I get:

```
Unable to Build entity manger factory

Caused by: Unable to start datastore provider
Caused by: OGM001219: Database testDB does not exist. Either create it yourself or set property 'hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database' to true.
```

I do have mongo running first, and it starts up listening on localhost:27017. I tried changing the database name to testDB but that didn't seem to make a difference. I am able to connect through the command line. Heres a screenshot at startup.

[image]

As a note, I'm not sure if the 3 other connections are normal.

My persistence file looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="jpa-mongodb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb"/>
  <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="testDB"/>
  <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="localhost"/>
  <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.username" value="" />
  <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.password" value="" />
</properties>
```

Sorry for the long post but I'm relativity new to this and most resources about Hibernate seemed to assume you could connect.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
<property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database" value="true" />
```

to the properties section in your persistence.xml